# Rails partial for collection, only display certain things for first element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I have a collection of elements I'm rendering in a partial, but I only want to display a certain element with the very first element.  My specific instance is displaying email addresses but I only want the email icon to show once next to the first instance (similar to how the Android Contacts app does).

I have a very "hacky" solution that uses instance variables in the view, which is not a good practice.  But I'm struggling to find a cleaner way to implement what I want.

The controller:

```
@email_addresses = EmailAddress.order(:primary) # primary is a boolean value
```

The partial:

```
# views/email_addresses/_email_address.html.erb
<div class="email-address">
  <% unless @email_icon_displayed
    <% @email_icon_displayed = true %>
    <div class="email-address-icon">
      <span class="icon email"></span>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="email-address-value">
    <%= email_address.value %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Calling partial in view:

```
<%= render partial: "email_addresses/email_address", collection: @email_addresses %>
```

This works properly and only displays the email icon for the first element, but instance variables in the view seems like a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a little late, but I had the same goal and I achieved it by using a "hidden" counter variable in Rails partial collections.

I called my partial collection like this:

```
<%= render partial: "questions/possible_answer",
          collection: question.possible_answers, as: 'value' %>
```

And inside my partial I can access the variable `value_counter`, which increments for each partial. So to run something with the first element only, I did it like this:

```
if value_counter == 0
  #do something
end
```

I think your case you would need to access it like this: `email_address_counter`

Found this solution here: https://coderwall.com/p/t0no0g/render-partial-with-collection-has-hidden-index

Comment: That should work as well.  I actually went with a CSS solution, printing all of the elements out to the page but styled to be `display: none;` and then used `element:first { display: block; }` (or something like that) to only display the first one.